# parsing assembly code in perl

Tags: perl, parsing

`0000000000033a1b        subq    $0x28,%rsp`

I am having trouble extracting 0x28 from the above line. I am able to extract subq from a big list of assembly code but i only want 0x28 since this gives me the stack size. I was thinking of using substr() function buy there are variations to it, another one could look like this:

`0000000000033a1c subq    $0x000000b8,%rsp`

in this case i only want 0x000000b8.

I am using perl.

Thank you.

Comment: To parse assembler, you probably want a finite state machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input of the following format always:

```
instruction_address operand $stack_size,register
```

you can do:

```
$a = '0000000000033a1b subq $0x28,%rsp';
$a =~s/^.*?\$(.*?),.*$/\1/;
print $a; # prints 0x28
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!. Could you please explain to me what is happening? I do not just want to copy and paste the code, i want to learn it. Thank you.

Comment: rashid, the regex reads:  ^ from start of string . any character * zero or more times ? non greedy modifier \$ a literal dollar sign ( begin capturing . any character * zero or more times ? non greedy modifier ) end capture group 1 , a literal comma .* everything else up to the $ end of string \1 substituted by capture group 1 ---  see Recipe 6.15 in the "perl cookbook" for an explanation of greedy modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Without code, my guess is that you're not escaping the dollar sign. Thus you are asking for it to match the end of the line, *and then* `'0x28'`.

In any regex, `/\$0x(\p{XDigit}+)/` should capture `'28'` out of that string.